# Exposing php functions/library as API in php

Tags: php, api

I have a library say something like this

```
function createCompany($json) {
  ...
}

function readCompany($json) {
  ...
}

function updateCompany($json) {
  ...
}
```

I want to expose them over an API say in the following format

http:// ... /api/api.php?fxn=updateCompany&jsn={"somejson":true}

http:// ... /api/api.php?fxn=readCompany&jsn={"somejson":false}

Is there a direct way were I can directly expose the above methods as API.

Comment: so fetch the vars of your request and route them to your method. Maybe you can do it dynamically with function_exists.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use classes for security reasons. And you should filter your fxn var. I did a small example for you but the json must be passed via $_POST not via $_GET:

```
<?php

class myclass {

    public function mymethod1($json) {        
        echo "mymethod1 called with argument:".var_export(json_decode($json),true);
    }

    public function mymethod2($json) {        
        echo "mymethod2 called with argument:".var_export(json_decode($json),true);
    }

    public function mymethod3($json) {        
        echo "mymethod3 called with argument:".var_export(json_decode($json),true);
    }
}

if(isset($_REQUEST['fxn'])) {

    $fxn = $_REQUEST['fxn'];
    $class = new myclass();
    if(method_exists($class, $fxn)) {

        $json = isset($_POST['jsn'])?$_POST['jsn']:"";

        $class->$fxn($json);
    }

}

?>
```